# How can I parse a string into different strings in C#?

Tags: c#

I just started work on a C# application. I need to break down a string into different parts. Is there an easy way to do this using C# patterns? I think I can do it with substrings but it might get messy and I want to do something that's easy to understand. Here's an example of the input:

```
AB-CDE-GHI-123-45-67-7777

variable1 = "AB-CDE-GHI"
variable2 = "123"
variable3 = "45"
variable4 = "67"
variable5 = "67-7777"

AB-CDE-GHIJKLM-123-45-67-7777

variable1 = "AB-CDE-GHIJKLM"
variable2 = "123"
variable3 = "45"
variable4 = "67"
variable5 = "67-7777"

AB-123-45-67-7777

variable1 = "AB"
variable2 = "123"
variable3 = "45"
variable4 = "67"
variable5 = "67-7777"
```

The first part of the string up until "123-45-67-7777" can be any length. Lucky for me the last part 123-45-67-7777 is always the same length and contains numbers that are zero padded.

I hope someone can come up with some suggestions for an easy method that uses regular expressions or something.

Input lines look like this:

```
aa-123-45-67-7777
HJHJH-123-45-67-7777
H-H-H--123-45-67-7777
222-123-45-67-7777
```

Comment: Please be precise. Do you have a fixed number of items between '-' or do you have fixed widths in chars?

Comment: Variable4 is duplicated in variable 5. Is that intentional?

Comment: Please also clarify the wanted output.

Comment: As mentioned in the original "Lucky for me the last part 123-45-67-7777 is always the same length and contains numbers that are zero padded."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `RegEx` for parsing this kind of input.

You can use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), in particular if the input is highly structured.

If you first split by `-` you will get a `string[]` with each part in a different index of the array.

The length property of the array will tell you how many parts you got and you can use that to reconstruct the parts you need.

You can rejoin any of the bit you need back.

```
string[] parts = "AB-CDE-GHI-123-45-67-7777".split('-');

// joining together the first 3 items:
string letters = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);

// letters = "AB-CDE-GHI"
```

If the number of sections is variable (apart from the last 4), you can use the `length` in a loop to rebuild the wanted parts:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < parts.Length - 4; i++)
{
  sb.FormatAppend("{0}-", parts[i]);
}
sb.Length = sb.Length - 1; // remove trailing -
```

Comment: I think he wants to split on '-' with the lines like variable 1 = "foo" being the results of the split

Comment: I don't think the _input_ contains '='

Comment: @Henk - I see. I mis-read the whole code block as a single input string :)

Comment: I really need to split into two. Where the first part is variable length and then the second part is the last 14 characters. Then I would need to split that last part based on the "-". I just thought reg expressions would be an easy way to do it.

Comment: @Alison - in that case, why confuse matters with 5 variables per input string?

Comment: Sorry if i'm not clear. My input lines look like this:
AB-CDE-GHIJKLM-123-45-67-7777
AB-CDE-GKLM-123-45-67-7777
FFF-123-45-67-7777
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-123-45-67-7777

Comment: @Alison - Please edit your question and add details explaining HOW the different strings could vary from each other. For example - will there _always_ be 4 numeric parts at the end? The number of character elements is variable? How so?

Comment: I also write this before Oded :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the last part is always a known length (14 characters) you could just do something like this:

```
var firstPart = inputLine.Substring(inputLine.Length - 14);
var secondPart = inputLine.Substring(0, inputLine.Length - 15); // 15 to exclude the last -
```

Then you can just do your string splitting and job done :)

Comment: Seems like the best approach, specially considering "Lucky for me the last [...] is always the same length". You just have to split the second part, but that should be easy.

Comment: I love how people always manage to come up with complicated solutions to easy problems :)

Answer (score 0):

like Oded say you can use string.Split

I edit my answer like you want

```
        string[] tab = textBox1.Text.Split('-');
        int length = tab.Length;
        string var1 = string.Empty;
        for(int i=0; i <= length-5 ; i++)
        {
           var1 = var1 + tab[i] + '-';
        }
        var1 = var1.Remove(var1.Length-1,1);
        string var2 = tab[length-4];
        string var3 = tab[length-3];
        string var4 = tab[length-2];
        string var5 = tab[length-2] + '-' + tab[length-1];
```

it's the same with the answer of @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya just you have make var1 + tab[i]

Comment: Yes but the first part is completely variable. THere could be anything before -123-45-67-7777

Comment: I have edit my answer and I make a test and it work ... if you have any doubt say it or pick the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Although it *is* possible to use here `String.Split`, a better solution, in my opinion, would be to tokenize the input and then parse it.

You can use tools such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for this purpose.

Comment: That would work fine, but isn't ANTLR a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a walnut in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] str = "AB-CDE-GHI-123-45-67-7777".Split('-')

int a = str.Length;

variable1="";

for(int i=0;i=<a-5;i++)
{
variable1=str[i]+"-"+variable1;
}
// last - remove
variable1 = variable1.Remove(variable1.Length-1,1);

variable2 = str[a-4]
variable3 = str[a-3]
variable4 = str[a-2]
variable5 = str[a-2]+"-"str[a-1];
```